# Duplicate data when scrolling a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I had a problem with tableview which is when the table first shows everything looks great but if I scroll up and and down, **NSLog(@"page name : %@", cell.pageName.text);** output value will be duplicate and it will cause the scrolling to be lagged. This is my code :

```
#import "HomeTVC.h"
#import "facebook.h"
#import "HomeTVCell.h"
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

@interface HomeTVC ()<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSDictionary *userPageLikesParams;
    NSArray *pagesInfo;
}
@end

@implementation HomeTVC


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    facebook *fb = [[facebook alloc] init];

    userPageLikesParams = @{@"fields": @"about,name,created_time,picture",@"limit": @"10"} ;
    [fb getUserPagelikes:userPageLikesParams completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *pagesResult) {

        if (pagesResult != nil) {
            pagesInfo = pagesResult[@"data"];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });
        }

    }];



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"table count : %d", (int)pagesInfo.count);
    if (pagesInfo == nil) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return pagesInfo.count;
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    HomeTVCell *cell = (HomeTVCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[HomeTVCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[pagesInfo[indexPath.row] valueForKeyPath:@"picture.data.url"]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
   // UIImage *pageProfileImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
   // NSLog(@"pages info : %@", pagesInfo[indexPath.row]);
   // NSLog(@"pages info image URL : %@", imageURL);


    // cache the image using sdwebimage
    cell.pageProfilePic.layer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    cell.pageProfilePic.layer.borderWidth= 2.0;
    cell.pageProfilePic.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.pageProfilePic.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    cell.pageProfilePic.layer.cornerRadius= 30.0;
    [cell.pageProfilePic sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"]];
    //cell.pageProfilePic.image = pageProfileImage;
    cell.pageName.text = pagesInfo[indexPath.row][@"name"];
    NSLog(@"page name : %@", cell.pageName.text);


    return cell;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see the point of your question, U can just remove the NSLog, it doesn't do anything for the user also?

Comment: You don't need the `if (cell == nil)` check.  The method you're using to dequeue a cell can't return nil.

Comment: You are loading images for each cell as that cell is provided and you technique doesn't use any caching so it will transfer a lot of data when you scroll only to throw that data away. Have a look at SDWebImage.

Comment: @Paulw11 he's doing correct isnt it, `sd_setImageWithURL` is both for download and caching and showing the image

Comment: I didn't notice that.  Yes, that is correct but first he is calling `dataWithContentsOfURL` which is pointless

Comment: @Paulw11 If u look closely I already used SDWebImage for caching.     **[cell.pageProfilePic sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"]]**

Comment: Yes, but you are also using the non-caching `dataWithContentsOfURL`

Comment: @Paulw11 i think its just unused code, U shoud remove that 2 lines TS

Comment: thank you @Paulw11, yes I tried to delete 'dataWithContentsOfURL'  and it's working perfectly, duhhh I've been wasting my time for 2 hours first this problem.

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be called each time a cell is about to scroll into view so you can expect to see multiple calls for the same row as you scroll so you would see your NSLog repeated.

Comment: thank you for explanation @Paulw11.